# AdminClient Websphere NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere-liberty

I am trying to connect to a remote Websphere Deployment manager from a Websphere Application Server. For this I am using the Websphere AdminClient, but I keep getting the error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/websphere/management/AdminClientFactory when I try to run this code:

```
props = new Properties();
props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_HOST, hostname);
props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE, AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE_SOAP);
props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_PORT, "8880");
props.setProperty(AdminClient.USERNAME, "<username>");
props.setProperty(AdminClient.PASSWORD, "<password>");
props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_SECURITY_ENABLED, "true");
try {
    adminClient = AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(props);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println("Something went wrong");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have added the com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.5.0.jar to the project.

Also here are the imports I have at the start

```
import java.util.Properties;
import com.ibm.websphere.management.*;
import com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException;
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I have solved this one myself.
If anyone has a similar problem add the com.ibm.ws.admin.client_x.x.x.jar to the folder WEB-INF/lib